# Image is not showing in image control asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my image control in UI:

```
  <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("strCLogo") %>' runat="server" width="200" Height="200"/>
```

And here is the C# code, I am grabbing the link of the image from database (customerstbl) but unable to bind it with image control, I can see the image link in the source but its not showing :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      int nCID = Convert.ToInt32(  Session["nCID"].ToString());

      DataClasses1DataContext _dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
      CustomersTbl _customer = new CustomersTbl();
      _customer = _dc.CustomersTbls.Where(a => a.nCID == nCID).FirstOrDefault();
     Image1.ImageUrl = _customer.strCLogo.ToString();

    }
```

here is how I am saving the link of the image in database, It seems I have an issue when I save the image link in database (it saves the whole path not the local directory path and image name)

```
string s = Server.MapPath("~/Imageslogo/") + Path.GetFileName(LogoUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
            LogoUpload.SaveAs(s);
```

Comment: Can you add the rendered output of the image to your question?

Comment: Why are you setting Image URL from both sides? Specify either from server side or client side.

Comment: Where is the image located? Are you linking to an image locally with a relative url? (If so it could be that the relative link is not correct because of where your page is located)

Comment: maybe url from root is wrong?! show us url and source(rendered output);

you can test output image url by pasting it in address bar and tell me is image showing?

Comment: look in your browsers dev tools (F12) console to see any failed requests, the path and reason. Also check that it's not being blocked by an Adblocker - I had an image which had path */advert/* which gets blocked

Comment: I can see in the source code of browser, It seems its relative link issue,yes I can see the image in browser but unable to see it using asp.net <img id="FeaturedContent_Image1" src="F:\projects\accounting\Accounting2014\Accounting2014\Imageslogo\100001203240.jpeg" style="height:200px;width:200px;" />

Comment: i can see the image http://localhost:35333/Imageslogo/100001203240.jpeg ,  I think there is the problem when i save the image link in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Save the image path as a relative path, configure root path globally

You are storing the path to the image as an absolute path. This is bad for several reasons, the main ones being:

- What happens if you deploy your app to a different server with a different file structure? your absolute path will be wrong
- What happens if you decide to move all of your images (but keep the structure of the image folder)? Again, your absolute path will be wrong.

I would advise you to store the **relative** image path in the database. In this case `/Imageslogo/100001203240.jpeg`. Then store the image **root** path (the part before the relative path) in your `Web.config` file. E.g. in the `appSettings`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="myApp.Imageroot" value="F:\projects\accounting\Accounting2014\Accounting2014" />
</appSettings>
```

You can get this `appSetting` value using the following code:

```
string myRoot = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("myApp.Imageroot");
```

With these two parts of the full path, you can:

- Use the relative path in your HTML output which will work fine on your web server
- Construct the full path by combining the root from your appSettings with the relative path in the database. You might use this is you need to manipulate the image programmatically or otherwise access the actual file instead of just passing the path to the client browser.
- Easily change the root by changing the appSetting

#### note

As an aside, if you are setting the `ImageUrl` property in code behind, then the `ImageUrl` attribute in your `.aspx` becomes pointless. So remove it:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" width="200" Height="200"/>
```

Comment: yes there was problem in image saving, now my code is working perfect here is that code  string imageLocation = @"~\Imageslogo\" + Path.GetExtension(LogoUpload.FileName);
                LogoUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imageLocation));

Comment: @user3098524 that looks like you're just making a file called `~\Imageslogo\jpg` (no file name or extension). You probably just want to do this: `imageLocation = @"~\Imageslogo\" + LogoUpload.FileName; LogoUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imageLocation));`

Comment: @user3098524 but I would advise using @ekad's code to generate the filename like this: `string imageLocation = string.Format("~/Imageslogo/{0}", Path.GetFileName(LogoUpload.PostedFile.FileName));`

Answer (score 1):

`F:\projects\accounting\Accounting2014\Accounting2014\Imageslogo\10000120324‌​0.jpeg` is not the correct value for [Image.ImageUrl Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imageurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the correct value is the relative path like `~/Imageslogo/10000120324‌​0.jpeg`.

You need to save the relative path to the database, use the code below to get the relative path

```
string imageLocation = string.Format("~/Imageslogo/{0}", Path.GetFileName(LogoUpload.PostedFile.FileName));
```

and save `imageLocation` to `strCLogo` column of `CustomersTbl` table.